# How to remove dictionary from list that is not empty completely?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list that looks like this:

```
 [{'name':'bob'},{'name':''},{'name':'test2'}]
```

The dictionary object is not really empty in the list, so how do I remove this 'empty' object that is not really empty? the new list should look like this:

```
 [{'name':'bob'},{'name':'test2'}]
```

I have tried:

```
[i for i in mylist if i]
```

but since the dictionary object is not completely empty I am not able to drop it, I think.

edit:

I put the below code in my JSON data clean up process like so:

```
for json in list:
   try:
      name = extract_json
      name = [i for i in name if len(i["name"]) > 0]
   except:
      name = None
```

I want to do the list clean only if it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. It is foolproof for dicts with more than one key and also data types other than string:

```
mylist = [{'name':'bob'},{'name':''},{'name':'test2'}]
new_list = [d for d in mylist if any(d.values())]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the `name` key of each `dict`, I would do it by checking the length of the name is greater than zero:

```
>>> d = [{'name':'bob'},{'name':''},{'name':'test2'}]
>>> [i for i in d if len(i["name"]) > 0]
[{'name': 'bob'}, {'name': 'test2'}]
```

Comment: How can I use your solution if the list has no empty dict values? When I run it over a list that has no empty values, I get error `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Comment: This edit will not work. think for example if `d = [{'name': 'bob'}, {'name': ''}, {'name': 'test2'}, {'name': 3}]`

Comment: try something like `[i for i in d if i['name']!='']`